# How to convert hcl tf file to json

Tags: json, terraform, hcl

want to read TF files with an node app. Therefore I want to read and parse hcl variable declarations. Is there any way to convert a `.tf` file to a `.tf.json` file via terraform cli? I‘ve tried `terraform show -json`, but this outputs my state without variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a dedicated tool for this.

This one comes up in Google search for "nodejs hcl Terraform library":

- https://github.com/NewSpring/node-hcl

(I have never seen it before, to be honest)

A general comment - parsing a language like HCL is not a trivial thing.